# Floor function to float and double values

Tags: java, math

How to apply floor function to float or double values to get integer.I got double Value:4.4497083717E10
float Value:4.4497084E10 out of my function.I got floor values as Floor of double:4.4497083717E10 Floor of float:4.4497084416E10.Is there a possibility that floor results in a integer??

Comment: You must apply `round` after `floor`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why would you want to round a floating point number that is guaranteed to represent an integer number already?

Comment: @ChristianRau Because you want a `long` and that's what `round` returns. A `double` never "represents" an integer, it only approximates it. The alternative, as explained in the answer by Andrzej Doyle, is to simply cast into a `long`. The result is exactly the same and the difference is only in your taste and what seems cleaner to you.

Comment: I want answer like: 4 for floor of float value(4.4497084E10) or double(4.4497083717E10).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know what a double is and what is returned by `floor` and am aware of the inherent truth of Andrzej's answer. That's why I wondered about the *"must apply round"* phrase from your comment. You don't round when all you need to do is cast. It isn't any cleaner anyway, since the additional round clouds the intention and makes you think why the represented number is not already integer. And by the way, a double can represent an integer (in the correct range of course), it doesn't just approximate it.

Comment: There you go -- you have stated your preference for the cast :) Someone else might say "when I see a `double` being coerced into a `long`, I shiver. Rounding is safer" -- but all that is in fact irrelevant since both operations are happening on the same line of code. This is the implementation of `round`: `(long)floor(a + 0.5d)`. Kind of the same thing, no?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Of course floating point numbers may be inexact and you always have to pay attention for any rounding issues, but we shouldn't give us dumber than we are and assume it never can represent an integer exactly, as that's not an implementation detail but an underlying concept of the floating point nature. That's why rounding is **never ever** safer after a floor. People stating that have abandoned any understanding of the underlying basic principles of computing for a strange dogmatic "never cast"-attitude.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So you mean whenever you write `round(floor(a))` it is equivalent to `(long)floor(floor(a)+0.5d)`? Right, makes much safer code. Well, everybody having at least a minimum sense of mathematics would shiver at that construct, even more so when hidden behind a "clean" `round`.

Answer (score 4):

> .Is there a possibility that floor results in a integer??

From a type perspective - no.  [`Math.floor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) is declared to return a `double`, and so will never return something with a static type of `int`.

That said, the documentation for the method declares that the returned value is *equal to* an integer.  So simply casting the returned result to an `int` will always give you the output you expect.

(That is, assuming your result is in range.  A `double` can hold larger numbers that an `int` can represent.  Check out [Narrowing primitive conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) for the technical details.  You may want to bounds-check your data to ensure it's always sensible to convert to `int`.)

Answer (score 1):

4.4497083717E10 is too large to be an `int`, you would have to cast to a `long`.

Casting to a long keeps the whole portion of the double making it the same as `Math.floor` for values which can be represented as a long. i.e.

```
long l = (long) Math.floor(4.4497083717E10);
```

is the same as

```
long l = (long) 4.4497083717E10;
```

---

```
System.out.println((int) Math.floor(4.4497083717E10));
System.out.println((long) Math.floor(4.4497083717E10));
System.out.println((long) 4.4497083717E10);
```

prints

```
2147483647   -- due to an overflow
44497083717
44497083717
```