# Ruby - get the floor of a float value?

Tags: ruby

How do I get the floor of a number like 188.50 to 188 in Ruby?  I do *not* want to `round` the number up.

Comment: None of the google / stack overflow search results could solve this?

Comment: At google.com type "ruby float round", then read any of the first 217 hits. Answers do not deserve upvotes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We expect to see evidence of your research and effort. SO isn't a "write code or a tutorial for me" site, we're here to help you debug your code. Please read "[ask]" including the links, and "[mcve]", along with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421.

Comment: This documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-floor

Comment: Did you try `188.50.floor`? Hint: it works...

Comment: Yes ,floor works. Is there any condition that i can make use of to convert such values using .floor and at the same time round values like 36.79 to 37 ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floor function to float and double values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243613/floor-function-to-float-and-double-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to truncate it, use `to_i`, if you want to round it use `round`:

```
> 188.51.to_i
=> 188

> 188.51.round
=> 189
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just want to have an integer, so why not convert to an integer ? Please note that it does not round to the nearest integer but truncates the integer (gets the highest integer that is lower than the float, so 188.99 will return 188).

```
(188.5).to_i
=> 188
(188.99).to_i
=> 188
```

If you want to round to the nearest integer :

```
(188.5).round
 => 189 
(188.49).round
 => 188
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I need to compare a few values in my application with  an Excel sheet which has the same values. But the excel seems to have decimals to two places and the application has integer values.For example- 36.98 to 37 , 515.67 to 516 and 188.5 to 188.  I will be writing a loop to compare the values in app and excel.How can i compare such values?